# "All arguments to functions are passed by value" in C, confusion about pass by reference in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

"All arguments to functions are passed by value"

This appears in book ["Pointers on C" by Kenneth A Reek.](https://www.scribd.com/doc/254553541/Kenneth-Reek-Pointers-on-C)

Even if a formal parameter is a pointer, I can understand how even pointers are passed by value. Essentially, a copy of the pointer is passed using which the element that is pointed to can be accessed. I am able to verify this by the following code.

```
//Code snippet 1
int main(void)
{
    int x = 10;//&x here is d9fccc
    pass_pointer(&x); 
    //Some other stuff
}

void pass_pointer(int *c) {
    //&c here is d9fbdc [note, this is different from &x in main]
    //c correctly returns d9fccc [i.e., c = &x]
    //Some other stuff
}
```

So far, so good.

However, when I attempt C++ classical pass by reference, I am not able to figure out how "All arguments to functions are passed by value" could be true.

Consider the following code.

```
    //Code snippet 2
    int main(void)
    {
        int x = 10;//&x here is d9fccc
        pass_by_reference(x); 
        //Some other stuff
    }

    void pass_by_reference(int &c) {
        //&c here returns d9fccc [note, this is same as &x in main]
        //Some other stuff
    }
```

What I am having trouble wrapping my head around are the following.

1. In Code snippet 1, it is clear that a copying occurs. Essentially, int *c = &x is implicitly carried out. So, c and x are two different variables that both point to the same address that happens to hold an integer. But, where is the copying occurring in code snippet 2?
2. If no copying is occurring in code snippet 2, could one generalize that whenever an actual argument is passed to a function, the compiler makes the formal parameter the lvalue and the actual argument as an rvalue? That is, in code snippet 2, this would mean int &c = x; The reason why I would hope this is true is because this also covers the case where explicit copying occurs as in code snippet 1.
3. What are the implication of code snippets in terms of their effect on the stack? If I understand correctly, in code snippet 1, when pass_pointer() is entered, c (whose address is d9fbdc) is pushed onto the stack. But what about code snippet 2? Is x itself pushed onto the stack?

Comment: "*I am not able to figure out how "All arguments to functions are passed by value" could be true.*" It would be true because ***C is not C++***.

Comment: You need to declare (or define) `pass_by_reference()` before calling it in C++.

Comment: "*the compiler makes the formal parameter the lvalue and the actual argument as an rvalue*" Also, that's not what "lvalue" and "rvalue" mean in C++.

Comment: In C++, it is not true that "all arguments to functions are passed by value"; some are passed by reference.  That usually means there is an implicit 'address-of' operation in the calling code, and there is an implicit 'dereference' in the called function for each and every reference to every variable passed by reference.  It simplifies the notation, at the cost of possibly mystifying those who are not use to seeing `x` modified by a call to a function passing `x` without an `&` in front of it.

Comment: _"However, when I attempt C++ classical pass by reference, I am not able to figure out how "All arguments to functions are passed by value" could be true."_ ..... it's not!!!!! C and C++ are two different languages. No better example could you find to prove that, than this.

Comment: A lot of text, but you missed to explain why **different** languages should behave the same and have the same featues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, when I attempt C++ classical pass by reference, I am not able to figure out how "All arguments to functions are passed by value" could be true.

This statement is kind of misleading. The semantics of a pass by reference are inherently different form a pass by value and you should view them as separate things (even if the compiler ends up implementing them similarly). C and C++ are wholly different languages and this is a good example of why.

Once you understand what the purpose of a reference is, things start making sense. Taking a reference of something is a way to create an alias for it, or in other words, refer to it with just a different name. For ex.:

```
 int a = 5;
 int &b = a;
```

This makes `b` an alias for `a`. That is, `b` is kind of a different name you've given to the thing `a`, but they are the same thing. This is why you can't reassign `b` to refer to something else. For its lifetime, it will be a synonym for the variable `a`.

This is inherently different to a pointer. For ex. the above code in pointers would be something like:

```
 int a = 5;
 int *b = &a;
```

but you could reassign `b` to point to something else and act as a "referrer" to that instead; this is something C++ references can't do.

So when you see a pass by reference in C++, it means something distinct; that you just want the parameter to serve as a synonym name for the object it is referring to. Although this behavior can be emulated with pointers (behind the scenes it this is the case), using a pointer vs using a reference would mean different things in terms of what you are intending to do.

In C you don't have the choice of passing things by reference so you **have** to emulate the behavior using pointers; the language isn't rich enough to have reference semantics. In C++ pass by reference is its own thing and you should think of it as such.

**An Example:**

Here is some code I wrote and the assembly output, which is what the compiler produces for the computer to run.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void print_struct(my_struct &s);    // implemented elsewhere


struct my_struct {
    int arr[10000];
};


int main() {
    my_struct s;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {     // fill array of struct
        s.arr[i] = i;
    }
    my_struct &s_ref = s;                   // print reference to s
    print_struct(s_ref);
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the assembly output **without any optimization**(O0) . Notice how the address of s is stored on the stack. This is passed as the parameter to print_struct and is just the address of `s`.

```
  000000000040085a <main>:
  40085a: 55                    push   %rbp
  40085b: 48 89 e5              mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40085e: 48 81 ec 50 9c 00 00  sub    $0x9c50,%rsp           
  400865: 48 c7 85 b0 63 ff ff  movq   $0x0,-0x9c50(%rbp)          # the counter i is stored at -0x9c50  
  40086c: 00 00 00 00
  400870: eb 1f                 jmp    400891 <main+0x37>
  400872: 48 8b 85 b0 63 ff ff  mov    -0x9c50(%rbp),%rax   
  400879: 89 c2                 mov    %eax,%edx
  40087b: 48 8b 85 b0 63 ff ff  mov    -0x9c50(%rbp),%rax
  400882: 89 94 85 c0 63 ff ff  mov    %edx,-0x9c40(%rbp,%rax,4)   # struct s starts at -0x9c40
  400889: 48 83 85 b0 63 ff ff  addq   $0x1,-0x9c50(%rbp)
  400890: 01
  400891: 48 81 bd b0 63 ff ff  cmpq   $0x270f,-0x9c50(%rbp)
  400898: 0f 27 00 00
  40089c: 76 d4                 jbe    400872 <main+0x18>
  40089e: 48 8d 85 c0 63 ff ff  lea    -0x9c40(%rbp),%rax
  4008a5: 48 89 85 b8 63 ff ff  mov    %rax,-0x9c48(%rbp)           # stores address of s at -0x9c48 which is what s_ref is
  4008ac: 48 8b 85 b8 63 ff ff  mov    -0x9c48(%rbp),%rax
  4008b3: 48 89 c7              mov    %rax,%rdi                    # the address stored at -0x9c48 is passed as parameter to print_struct method
  4008b6: e8 72 ff ff ff        callq  40082d <_Z12print_structR9my_struct>
  4008bb: b8 00 00 00 00        mov    $0x0,%eax
  4008c0: c9                    leaveq
  4008c1: c3                    req
```

With some basic typical optimization, the assembly becomes as below. Note how in this case, the reference is never even stored on the stack.

```
000000000040099a <main>:
40099a: 48 81 ec 48 9c 00 00    sub    $0x9c48,%rsp               # s is stored at 0x9c48
4009a1: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax                  # counter of for loop stored in register
4009a6: eb 07                   jmp    4009af <main+0x15>
4009a8: 89 04 84                mov    %eax,(%rsp,%rax,4)
4009ab: 48 83 c0 01             add    $0x1,%rax
4009af: 48 3d 0f 27 00 00       cmp    $0x270f,%rax
4009b5: 76 f1                   jbe    4009a8 <main+0xe>
4009b7: 48 89 e7                mov    %rsp,%rdi                  # doesn't put address of s onto stack. Just passes the address straight as a parameter to print_struct
4009ba: e8 42 ff ff ff          callq  400901 <_Z12print_structR9my_struct>
4009bf: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
4009c4: 48 81 c4 48 9c 00 00    add    $0x9c48,%rsp
4009cb: c3                      retq
```

Comment: Thanks for taking effort to write a detailed reply. Things are a lot clearer now. So, suppose I have a huge typedef struct S, with sizeof(S) being, say, 1000 bytes. Suppose I also have an object struct S s; Then, supposed I create a reference/alias of this by struct S & r = s; Then, it is not that case that 1000 bytes are taken up by r, correct? The memory overload would possibly be lot lesser. What the compiler has to do is to simply store some place that memory address 5172 (say) is the beginning of both structures r as well as s. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tryer Yes it won't create an entire copy of the original struct. It might just hard code the address of the original one everywhere you use the reference, or it may (behind the scenes) store the address in a pointer as you suggest and pass that around.

Comment: @Tryer I added some assembly explanation to show you what I mean.

Comment: The bottom line is that the C++ language spec doesn't define *how* a reference is implemented, only how programs that use references must *behave*.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie well said.

Answer (score 3):

The logic is different in C and C++.   In C, all arguments are passed by value.   In C++, all arguments that are not passed by reference are passed by value.

In both C and C++, the act of pass by reference can be emulated by passing a pointer, and dereferencing the pointer.

```
void pass_pointer(int *p)
{
    printf("%d\n", *p);
    *p = 42;
}
```

`p` itself is passed by value, but this code effectively uses `*p` as a reference, and allows the value of whatever `p` points at to be printed, and then changed to `42`.   Note that this ASSUMES `*p` refers to a valid `int` (or, equivalently, that `p` points to a valid `int`).   If `*p` does not refer to a valid `int` (e.g. `p` is `NULL`, or points at something that doesn't exist as far as the program is concerned) then both usages of `*c` give undefined behaviour (which means anything can happen, but common practical results vary between printing a garbage value and a program crash).

Both `p` and `*p` are valid entities (the value of the pointer, and the value of what it points at).  Forgetting the `*` is a common source of programmer error when working with pointers, and can cause cryptic bugs that are very difficult to find and correct.

The above example works the same in both C and C++.

In C++, there is an alternative that is not supported in C - pass by reference.

```
void pass_reference(int &r)
{
    printf("%d\n", r);
    r = 42;
}
```

This achieves the same thing as the `pass_pointer()` example, but there are a few key changes.

- `r` is passed by reference.   No pointer in the code (although a compiler might emit the same object code, and treat a reference like a pointer behind the scenes, that's a compiler implementation detail, not something the C++ programmer needs to care about).
- Dereferencing `r` is not permitted - using`*r` in this function will not compile.  So all of the possible errors with forgetting a `*` are avoided.
- `r` is guaranteed (by language rules) to be a valid reference.   There is no undefined behaviour introduced by using `r`.  So there is no need for `pass_reference()` to check if `r` is a valid reference before using it.
- There is no such thing as a "reference to a reference" in C++ (whereas there are pointers to pointers in C).

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. Question: When you say "r is passed by reference" towards the end of your post, no new variable is created in the system, for instance, a local variable or else a variable that is pushed onto the stack, etc. Yes? That is no copying occurs at all. r is NOT a copy of another variable in another function which calls pass_reference().

Comment: @Tryer I notice you keep asking about whether a new variable is created and pushed onto the stack. What the compiler chooses to, or doesn't choose to do, behind the scenes is not something you should worry about. The truth is, a lot of local variables don't end up getting pushed on the stack (they stay in registers), so the question is hard to answer. The compiler is a beast and can do a multitude of unpredictable things. The point is, reference semantics are a **language specific** construct and your questions should revolve around what the language is saying references should do.

Comment: Passing something by reference means not passing a copy of it.

Answer (score 2):

You are considering 2 different cases of 2 different language.

In C **All arguments to functions are passed by value**

And pass by reference is simply the same reference to the object. ANy changes reflects in the callee.

> In pass by reference (also called pass by address), a copy of the
>   address of the actual parameter is stored. Use pass by reference when
>   you are changing the parameter passed in by the client program.

And also we can imitate pass by reference in some form in ( not exactly) in pass-by-value environment.

The thing in case of pointer you need to have 2 memory access. But in case of references it is automatically dereferenced.

### One key thing that you are waiting to hear...

If you take a peek at gcc generated assemble then you will see in case of reference also a pointer is passed. But only thing is here we are accessing it directly not via some other variable (as in case of C pass of pointer to a function)

### Hands on experience if you want (if you don't believe me)

Write a c++ code where you simply use pointer and also pass by reference. 
Then use `gcc -S progname.c` and check the `progname.s` file ...you will see address being stored.

Comment: what does this mean in terms of pass by reference arguments/parameters in C++ and where they are when a function is called. Are they pushed onto the stack?

Comment: @Tryer you still seem to be failing to understand that "All arguments to functions are passed by value" does not apply to C++

Comment: @M.M does this mean in C++, code snippet 2, the compiler does not push x onto the stack?

Comment: @Tryer there might not be a stack at all. The compiler does whatever is necessary to achieve the specified behaviour (which is that `c` in the function denotes the same variable as `x` in main). You could look at the assembly that a particular compiler generates to see what is happening on a particular system

Comment: @M.M.: If someone doesn't use gcc ..can he reliably use this to generate assembly? https://godbolt.org/

Answer (score 2):

The best way to understand references is to understand two rules:

1. A reference is the same thing as a pointer, except:
2. Every time a reference is used, it get automatically dereferenced, as if by the `*` operator, as the first order of business before using it.

Well, there's also a third rule:

3. When a reference is constructed, it's as-if the address-of, `&`, operator is applied to whatever you're creating the referenece to.

... but that's not important for the purpose of this discussion. Anyway, the first two rules are the most important ones. If you keep those rules in mind, then you can consider that:

```
int &c
```

is the same thing as:

```
int *c
```

Except that every time you use this `c` in any context, it gets automatically dereferenced, used like you've written `(*c)`so in an expression like:

```
int a = b + c;
```

If `c` is a reference, then this is equivalent to `int a = b + (*c);`.

If you make this mental adjustment -- replace a reference variable with a pointer, and slapping on a dereference operator everywhere it's actually used -- you should be able to figure out the answer to your own question all by yourself, and understand that when references are passed to a function, they're passed passed by value, like everything else. There's nothing really different about them, here.

Comment: "int &c" is the same thing as "int *c". If I have int &c = x and int *d = &x, then &c = &x, while &d != &x.

Comment: This is *a* way to understand references... calling it "the best" is presumptuous. Personally I think it's both wrong and poor

Comment: That, and you cant change references. And they don't have their own addresses. And `int &c` barely behaves like `int *c` even at a stretch.  And the other numerous reasons you haven't mentioned.